# Javascript scope and anonymous functions: How can I pass a parameter object to jQuery jEditable plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, jeditable

[EDIT: Simplified question and code example I hope!]

Hi. I need a bit of help with JS scope and anonymous functions.

I want to put a generic 'set up' function wrapper around the jQuery 'jEditable' plugin (http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable) so that I can pass in the jEditable parameters I want and change the behaviour of the plugin, rather than keep repeating the jEditable code, with just a couple of changes to the parameters each time.

See http://jsfiddle.net/gcm5r/ for my code example.

I simply don't know how to pass a parameter object 'mySettings' through the wrapper function and have jEditable pick up those parameters in the callback I have created.

I'm sure this is a question to do with scope and constructing the call back correctly.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Sorry, but I'm confused about what parameters you want to pass and where you want to pass them.

Comment: Sorry. Normally, the jEditable function is called like this: http://jsfiddle.net/EDASF/ I want to pass in the parameters {type    : 'textarea',submit  : 'OK'} as a variable 'mySettings' in my function so that I can change the behaviour of the jEditable plugin with this one function wrapper.

Comment: Well it's hard to tell why what you've already got won't work. One problem with your first jsfiddle is that you pass "dd" in to that function, but the code in the function expects the parameter to be the "id" of an element, not a tag name.

Comment: If you could make a fiddle that actually works, except for the lack of being able to pass parameters the way you want, it would be far easier to understand the issue I think.

Comment: Hi Pointy. I'm so sorry. I have corrected and better explained my example code here: http://jsfiddle.net/gcm5r/

Comment: Well it's still confusing, and your code *still* looks like something that will work. Your comment that "mySettings is out of scope" is just not correct. Inside that outer function ("makeElementEditable"), that parameter is definitely visible to all code, including the call to the "editable()" function.

Comment: <Sigh> Not a great start for my first post here. My question has be answered though. Thank you all for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that what you're trying to do: http://jsfiddle.net/LekisS/yNLu6/7/ ?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Except that I have to use the 'Callback' in jEditable as I gave in my code example, as this is the only way to properly control the AJAX functionality I need.